# Resize HTML text area based on document width

Tags: html

I need a way to resize a `textarea` based on the width of the entire page.  I have a `div` absolutely positioned next to it with a width of 40%, and I want to have my `textarea` take up the rest of the page.  I know I can't just say `<textarea width="60%"...>` because `textarea` doesn't have a `width` attribute.  Is there any way to tell `textarea` to take up a relative amount of space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the textarea width using CSS.
http://jsfiddle.net/stevelove/uFDB4/

Comment: Sweet.  Thanks.  I'll have to remember jsfiddle.net.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Setting the textarea width using CSS works just fine when the position is not absolute. http://jsfiddle.net/F7a6Z/

Answer (score 1):

Again, use CSS. But use *external* CSS:

### style.css

```
#teh-div {
    width:500px;
}
#teh-div textarea {
    width:65%;
}
```

### document.html

```
<div id="teh-div"><textarea ></textarea></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in another div. That's simple, and will work.

```
<div id="textareaWrapper" style="width:'60%'"><textarea>text</textarea></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Textarea doesn't have a width element, but you can use CSS to define the width of a textarea.  You can use the following code to do so.

```
<div style="width: 500px;"><textarea style="width: 65%;"></textarea></div>
```

In the above code, the div will be 500 px wide, and the text area will be 65% of the width of the div.